# Data validation drop down list from a range, than only displays values conditionally WITHOUT using a second calculation sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a function in a data validation drop down list that shows options from a range A2:A30, but I only want it to show options that have a value greater than or equal to 10 in the column over B2:B30. The cell I am referring to is O5.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irEVri9opqp5v8MraOdBsvNO6NG8CtjBEgnOC7bufrM/edit?usp=sharing)

The purpose/objective is that I have a linear regression formula building projections based on past data about the selected mode, and I don't want the dropdown to be able to select options that have a count less than 10 (because the projection is wildly inaccurate). **I would like to do this without creating a second tab or hidden section that populates a second range under those conditions, and then rerouting the data validation to that range.**

Any suggestions towards this goal or towards learning about the general idea will be appreciated.

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: @player0 Figured. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem? If so, could you put it as an answer? Thanks

Comment: @Emel I was able to manipulate the data in a way that solved the problem. I sorted the range the drop-down was pulling from and then limited the drop down selection to the top 5 of the list. If you're interested in a specific answer let me know and I can provide the sheet.

Comment: It would be great if you posted the answer. If someone else in the community is in the same situation, your answer would be very helpful.

Comment: @Emel Well I'm hesitant to post my solution because its not a direct answer to my original question. I will post it anyways though.

Comment: @Emel posted an answer and also put the formula in the example sheet.

Comment: That's great!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have come to an indirect solution by manipulating the data in a different way specific to my example sheet. I changed the data validation drop-down range from A2:A30 to A2:A5, and then changed the `=unique()` formula to a query that fill in the options, the count for that option, and then sorts it ascending so that the top spots are the ones with the most data. Therefore the linear regression will be somewhat limited to the options with better data.

The query is:

`=query('Data Sheet'!$A$2:$C, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc label count(A) ''")`

All of the rest of the formulas are built off of that query, including the data validation drop down. It is [in my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irEVri9opqp5v8MraOdBsvNO6NG8CtjBEgnOC7bufrM/edit?usp=sharing).